# datetime.tryparse always return false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am following a course in asp.net and I'm new to c#

I created a form that has an input field for date ,it always return
invalid message
below is the code for the input :

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, new { @class = "form-control",placeholder="eg 1 Jan 2015" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Date)
    </div>
```

this is the model property I've created for that input field :

```
[Required]
[FutureDate]
public string Date { get; set; }
```

and this is the code of the futuredate data annotation where the problem occurs :

```
public class FutureDate : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            DateTime dateTime;
            var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value),
                "d MMM YYYY",
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None,out dateTime);
            return (isValid && dateTime > DateTime.Now);

        }
    }
```

although I noticed when debugging that the datetime variable does not updated
with the input field value and returns {01/01/0001 12:00:00}

Comment: And the date you are trying to parse is exactly `"eg 1 Jan 2015"`?

Comment: @Charlieface the date is "1 Nov 2030"

Comment: [Lower case `yyyy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#yyyySpecifier)

Answer (score 4):

The year specifier is lowercase. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for reference.

```
var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(Convert.ToString(value),
            "d MMM yyyy",
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,out dateTime);
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BCQdJr

Compare to non-working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DIx7Jn

Comment: The validation error still existing even after changing yyyy to lowercase

Comment: Please double check your input, i.e.: what value is returned by `Convert.ToString(value)`? This snippet works. No error and it returns `true` for "1 Jan 2030".